# DJANGO - class Meta / varibales db_table

Tags: django, variables, meta, metaclass

I would like to get a variable in my meta class

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        db_table = 'bikes_table'
        managed = False
```

I want to get a variable from `self` like above  :

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        db_table = 'bikes_table' if self.customers=True else 'cars_table'
        managed = False
```

Is it possible de get variable ?
Thank you

Comment: Meta doesn't have access to `self`. It really is only for defining metadata for the model. So I don't think this is possible.

Comment: "self" does not exist at class declaration time - only when the views are called.

Comment: I think what you want is a base model definition which you can then inherit for your `cars` and `bikes` model ...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the surface problem is that "self" won't be available at class definition time, of course.

Some of the fields in the Metadata could have values that could change at runtime, for each instance, those will accept callback functions instead of static values (but looking at the documentation, there seems to be none)

Now, the table corresponding to a certain Model is used by the ORM and will be bound at the class level. Doubly so because a lot of the queries dealing with a class have to issue database statements *without* having an instance, as is the case for any *query*.  I mean, in your example, a `vehicle.objects.all()` would have to query both database tables and bring the results together in the same response.

It *could* be done by subclassing Django's internal Queryset databases, and carefully rewriting it to look at the "table" model meta data in a custom way, but it would be prone to error.

So, you'd rather rethink your design.  It is easier to simply have a Vehicle base class, just use "Vehicle" on your forms and relations, and derive the Bicycle and Car classes from that - either a car or a bicycle could be used wherever a vehicle can. Django provides support for the relationship itself with [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)